# access and modify array through include file and function

Tags: php

Not sure why I can't modify an array by calling a function that includes a file that then references that array.

Here is the situation:

config.php:

```
$db['default']['password'] = "password";  
$db['default']['database'] = "dbname";

check_if_local_file_exists(__FILE__);
```

---

```
function check_if_local_file_exists( $calling_file )  
{
   $local_version = dirname( $calling_file ) . '/' . basename( $calling_file , '.php' ) . '.local';

   if ( file_exists ( $local_version ) ) {    
     @include_once( $local_version );  
   }  

} // function
```

---

config.local:

```
global $db;

$db['default']['password'] = "password_modififed";  
$db['default']['database'] = "dbname_modified";
```

---

Not sure why I can't modify the $db array in the included file: config.local that is included by the check_if_local_file_exists function.

When I print_r ($db ) after calling check_if_local_file_exists(**FILE**) in config.php, the $db array has not been modified at all. . .

Comment: Why have you added an @ to suppress errors? There could be an warning that the file could not be included. Maybe try a require.

Comment: Are you sure your config.local is being included at all?

Comment: I have removed the @ to suppress errors. You are right, no need for it. I have concluded that config.local is being included. var_dump after the global declaration does not produce anything, confirming that this is a scope problem. . .my suspicion being that config.php is included in a class or function itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the file at load. Php isn't reparsed after initial load. Try not using the check function and just include the file directly as a test and see if that works for you. Also, try

```
return @include(....);
```

instead of just

```
@include(....);
```

Comment: There's no restriction on when you can include a file in PHP, do you have any references for that statement?

Comment: @Jacob what I mean to say is he is not returning anything from the function itself so it is not parsing it.

Comment: A return isn't required either. The function isn't expected to return anything, the included file is modifying a global variable.

Comment: I would definitely agree with Jacob when he says remove the @ and make sure error reporting is on as it should be throwing you an error if the path is mixed up.

Comment: That is correct. In this case, my included file is modifying a global variable and I would think no return is needed. If I do not use the function, but instead include the file directly in config.php, I am able to modify the variables with no problem. I would like, however, to use the function.

Comment: I removed the @, but no error was triggered. I have also verified that I have error reporting on. Also, just to clarify, I have confirmed that the function is being called.

Comment: Try doing this. Remove everything inside the function and call the include directly to the file in there to see if there is a miscommunication going on within the actual function itself.

Comment: I have a feeling the if statement is returning false

Comment: when I put a statement inside the function such as "I am called," it echos. The same thing is true if I put the statement in config.local, which tells me that it is being included. config.php may be part of another function or class. . . In this case, wouldn't global access the variables in scope with the call scope ? In other words, wouldn't there be a scope hierarchy ?

Comment: what version of php are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the @ in front of the include call. It could hide important debugging information.

Is the $db variable in config.php created in the global scope? That is the lines you've shown us are not within a function or within a file that is included by a function?

Have you verified that the file is being include? This can be as simple as echoing "I've been included!" in the config.local

Additionally if the file has been included, try `var_dump($db);` after the global declaration but before you modify it, and ensure you are accessing the right variable (this will answer the question about scope as well).

I suspect the file may not be being included and you are not being warned because of the @ symbol, or the fact that it does nothing if the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

In all your conditions, I do not see a single debug statement such as,

else echo 'file does not exist';

How do you know if the file even exists where you say it does?
When using include(....) do not make all those checks and then use the superessor operator. That's so much time and resources wasted. 
Use one. Most likely, the condition checks since the suppression is way slower and add some debug info there.

If it is a config file, why make it optional? I'd rather use an include. Configurations are essential.

Moreover, the values in the config local are the same in your example. There shouldn't be any modification.

---

So in your test, are the values different? If yes, it should work. 
If you are modifying the array outside a function, try removing the global declaration. 
Try a simple echo in the included file to see if it executes. 
Lastly, rename the file with a .php extension and try again.

---

Try wrapping your code in php tags inside the include file. 
If you know which variable you are modifying before hand, being the global statement before you include the file. That should solve it.

Comment: I have confirmed the file exists and that the function is being called. The check_if_local_file_exists function simply checks that a local file exists and then uses that local file to overwrite potential config variables. This allows for an easy way for our team to work in subversion and just add a file such as "database.local" or "config.local" to the same directory as the file in which the above function is called. I can get everything working if I remove the function and just place the body of the function in config.php